# Question on the class number of real quadratic fields

Tags: number-theory, quadratic-forms

I know that it is a well-known theorem that for a fixed $n$ there are only finitely many $D<0$ such that $h(\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{D}))=n$. However, I was told that this is not true for the case when $D>0$. I think I have an idea (although it is most likely wrong), but I am curious as to why it might be wrong. In D.A. Buell's "Binary Quadratic Forms" Theorem $6.19$ states the following

> a) If the discriminant $\Delta$ of the quadratic field $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{\Delta})$ is negative, then the class group and the narrow class group are isomorphic
>
> b) If the discriminant $\Delta$ of the quadratic field $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{\Delta})$ is positive and a solution exists to the equation $$x^2-\Delta y^2=-4$$ then the class group and the narrow class group are isomorphic
>
> c) If the discriminant $\Delta$ of the quadratic field $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{\Delta})$ is positive, and no solution exists to the equation
> $$x^2-\Delta y^2=-4$$ then the class group consists of the subgroup of squares of the narrow class group.

Furthermore, I saw this post for showing that [the size of the narrow class group is a multiple of class number](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3584795/the-narrow-class-number-is-a-multiple-of-the-class-number). Thus, shouldn't it be the case that if I fix some number $n$, and I wish to show that there are only finitely many positive $D>0$ such that $h(\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{D}))=n$, it would be sufficient to show that there are only finitely many classes of binary quadratic forms of a given discriminant which is true? Perhaps, there is something wrong with the case that $$x^2-\Delta y^2=-4$$ has no solutions as then the class group is isomorphic to the squares of the narrow class group. Any help on where my confusion might lie would be appreciated.

Comment: it is suspected that, for prime $p \equiv 1 \pmod 4,$  there are infinitely many $h( \mathbb Q ( \sqrt p)) = 1.$

Comment: anyway, for prime $p \equiv 1 \pmod 4,$  there are always solutions to $x^2 - p y^2 = -1$   and thus $-4$